# extract columns with certain characters and store them in separate file

Tags: text-processing, sed

I have a big file with over 1 million columns and 800 rows. The first row is the chromosome's name(Ha412HOChr01,Ha412HOChr02,.....Ha412HOChr17) with the SNP position on each chromosome. in Total their are 17 chromosomes. I want to extract columns for each chromosome (Ha412HOChr01,Ha412HOChr01,Ha412HOChr01,....,Ha412HOChr17) and store them in a separate file.

```
"Ha412HOChr01:180159" "Ha412HOChr01:210724" "Ha412HOChr01:303270" "Ha412HOChr01:303280"....... "Ha412HOChr17:303402"
0 1 0 0 ......0
0 1 0 0 ......0
0 1 0 0 ......0
0 2 0 0 ......0
0 1 1 1 ......1
0 2 0 0 ......0
```

my desired output for example for chromosome 1:

```
out.chrom1
"Ha412HOChr01:180159" "Ha412HOChr01:210724" "Ha412HOChr01:303270" "Ha412HOChr01:303280" 
0 1 0 0 
0 1 0 0
0 1 0 0 
0 2 0 0 
0 1 1 1 
0 2 0 0 
0 0 0 0 
0 2 0 0
0 1 2 2
```

Comment: did you have tried my answer https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/545356/195582 ? Do you need more infos?

Comment: I could not get miller running

Comment: what's your operative system?

Answer (score 0):

If your field separator is one space, using Miller (https://github.com/johnkerl/miller) you can run

```
mlr --csv --fs " " cut -r -f "Ha412HOChr01:" input.txt
```

to obtain "Ha412HOChr01" data

```
Ha412HOChr01:180159 Ha412HOChr01:210724 Ha412HOChr01:303270 Ha412HOChr01:303280
0 1 0 0
0 1 0 0
0 1 0 0
0 2 0 0
0 1 1 1
0 2 0 0
```

Then you can create a for loop and create all your files.